# Two different version of install lib

Tags: linux, installation, protocol-buffers

I'm checking with installed protobuf lib version on my system and I'm surprised with, following **/usr/bin/protoc --version** return **V2.4.1** and following **protoc --version** return **V3.0.0**.

Why this is so, am I missing any **user account** related installation concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two versions of protocol buffers installed.

If you write `$ which protoc` you will see where the protoc environment variable points to. Probably `/usr/local/bin/protoc`

You can change that to `/usr/bin/protoc`, but how depends on how it is set initially and what system you are on. Google or [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) will help you with that.

Comment: No, nothing like that, one is default for my system so let's say if I'm building an application from my system then it will use /usr/local/bin/protoc compiler else for regular use it will uses install compiler version, in my case it's V3.0.0.

Comment: What do you mean "default for my system"? What is the output of  `$ which protoc`? What system are you on? How did you install protocol buffers?

Comment: ..default mean install protoc version by sudo-apt command and this command display linux installation directory "/usr/local/bin/protoc' as expected.

Comment: You must have done something else, aptitude places it in `/usr/bin/protoc` as stated [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/protobuf-compiler/filelist). If you want help, posting the output of `$ which protoc` might be a good start, as well as telling what system you are on.

Comment: as mention output coming **/usr/local/bin/protoc** and I'm using Ubuntu13.10.

Comment: Then you have to do as I said in my answer, change the env. var. to point to `/usr/bin/protoc`. Some details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90589/discussion-between-petersv-and-shubh).